# Rails link_to ruby variable in onclick javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is Wrong with this statement
It is showing syntax error

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion("+ question.id +");return false;"%>
```

But

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion();return false;"%>
```

is correctly generating the below code

```
<a title="Delete" onclick="removeQuestion();return false" class="action remove" href="/quizzes/remove/1"><img src="/images/cancel.png?1290165811" alt="Cancel"></a>
```

Comment: Please show the syntax error that you're getting.

Comment: what is the syntax error message?

Comment: ALso please only tag the questions with the *language*, additional tags such as "helpers" / "link-to" are not helpful and are just tagspam :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you wrote

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion("+ question.id +");return false;"%>
```

This bombs because `question.id` is a Fixnum. You would get `can't convert Fixnum into String` `TypeError`.

Ways to solve this

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion("+ question.id.to_s +");return false;"%>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion('#{question.id}');return false;"%>
```

This will send the question id as a string to your removeQuestion javascript function.

OR

```
<%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion(#{question.id});return false;"%>
```

This will send the question id as an integer to your removeQuestion javascript function.

Comment: The last one will not send it as an integer but as an double, because JavaScript only knows double. Ok, it is compatible with 32bit integers, but still.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%= link_to image_tag('cancel.png'), {:action => 'remove', :id => question.id}, :title=>'Delete', :class=>'action', :onclick=>"removeQuestion($(this).attr('id'));return false;"%>
```

This will work